# How to use pipe to parse output of a command

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, pipe, ifconfig

I want to process the output of a process, say ifconfig. As you all know output of ifconfig is a list  of lines containing `inet addr:` mask: etc. But I want to extract the ip alone[from inet addr: field] and list it. is it possible with pipe command? like

```
ifconfig | What should be here?
```

I want the output of this command as list of `inet addresses` (of different access points if present).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) as shown on [this](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/golfing-the-extraction-of-ip-addresses-from-ifconfig/) site. I've posted an excerpt here which produces your desired result:

`ifconfig | awk '/dr:/{gsub(/.*:/,"",$2);print$2}'`

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
 ifconfig -a|grep inet| awk -F' ' '{print $2}'
```